# GA/UA - Custom dimension reducing number of pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, dimension, universal-analytics

Currently using a custom dimension to pass the author name of each article viewed. The author name is appearing in GA but the only problem is that the number of pageviews are significantly reduced when we apply the custom dimension to a report.

For example:

/article/example : 1900 pageviews (without author name in the report)

/article/example "Bob Smith" : 800 pageviews (when using author name in the report)

Using GTM debug, we can see the custom dimension is being passed with the author name so i'm a little confused as to why the discrepancy in the figures.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that author was not set or have different value in author.
Are you trying same date ranges?

Comment: Hi @Suketu, same date ranges and testing on the same article so the author name is being set and passed.

Comment: Can you share your website? Also provide what combination of dimensions/metrics you're using.

Comment: Sorry, can't share the url, i could send it by email.

Comment: @Ninjasys did you emailed?