# GA/GTM: Applying custom dimension reduces pageviews

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a GA custom dimension ("Byline") to capture the author's name for each article on my site. However, applying Byline as a secondary dimension on a report for a page drastically reduces the pageviews for no apparent reason. Specifically, one page had 21,479 pageviews in the past week. With "byline" added as a secondary dimension, the total pageviews decrease to 13,398 -- it doesn't introduce a "null" or "not set" as an option, it just doesn't seem to track those pageviews.

The custom dimension is based on a GTM variable (DOM Element, CSS Selector) that is part of the Page View tag, so it should fire on all pages. Why is that not the case? The report has the same date range in both cases.

There appears to be a similar discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22938020/ga-ua-custom-dimension-reducing-number-of-pageviews) but it wasn't answered. Any advice is appreciated, thanks!

(edit: misspelled "custom", naturally)

Comment: GA does not, by itself, register a "not set" value if you do not send a value for a dimension. Instead it will omit hits for which the dimension was not set from any report where the dimension is present. Since this is not code-related (other in the sense that you need to set a default null value yourself) I guess this is off-topic.

Comment: Any chance your report with the secondary dimension was a sampled view?

Comment: Oddly enough, when I add the secondary dimension to Behavior --> All Pages, I get the yellow shield icon indicating sampling, but it says it's based on 100% of sessions.